# Qt single slot for all buttons in a QDialog

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way, in Qt, to have a single function that will be called when ANY button in a `QDialog` is clicked? Something like this:

```
void on_any_button_clicked(QPushButton* button)
```

I've used 'connect' for every single button however my `QDialog` has about 40 buttons so I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I would wrap the button creation code in a function that sets up a single button, including connections. You may want to do other things to all buttons too, such as tooltips etc, so wrapping it now can come in handy later.

Comment: You could do something like: `connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [&](){ on_any_button_clicked(btn); } );` (syntax might be slightly off, going from memory)

Comment: @ChrisMM That's what I am doing now but I have 40 of them so it takes around 160 lines just to do that so I was hoping for a "better" way

Comment: Well, you can just iterate through all child widgets, check whether they're a QPushButton, and then performing the connect there.

Comment: If you have 40 buttons, you may want to group them into a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) and use its signals

Comment: You can search children of the widget, and connect them in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to do it in this way:

```
// In dialog's constructor
for (QPushButton* button : findChildren<QPushButton*>())
{
    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [&]
    {
        on_any_button_clicked(button);
    });
}
```

Comment: The downside of this is creation of N  functor objects and N connector pairs.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to connect the buttons to a click handling function that does not take a `QPushButton*` argument and then determine which button was clicked via casting `sender()` to a `QPushButton*` in the function:

```
class Buttons : public QDialog
{
public:
    Buttons(int n, QWidget* parent = nullptr)
        : QDialog(parent), buttons_(n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            buttons_[i] = new QPushButton(
                QString("button #") + QString::number(i+1)
            );
        }

        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        for (auto btn : buttons_) {
            layout->addWidget(btn);
            connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Buttons::handleButtonClick);
        }

        setLayout(layout);
        setWindowTitle("buttons");
        setModal(false);
    }

private:

    void handleButtonClick() {
        QPushButton* clicked = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText(clicked->text() + " clicked.");
        msgBox.exec();
    }

    std::vector<QPushButton*> buttons_;
};
```

Or you could use a click handling function that *does* take a button pointer argument and connect the buttons' click signals to lambdas that call the handling function by capturing the appropriate button pointer in their closures:

```
class Buttons2 : public QDialog
{
public:
    Buttons2(int n, QWidget* parent = nullptr)
        : QDialog(parent), buttons_(n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            buttons_[i] = new QPushButton(
                QString("button #") + QString::number(i + 1)
            );
        }

        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        for (auto btn : buttons_) {
            layout->addWidget(btn);
            connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked,
                [this, btn]() {
                    handleButtonClick(btn);
                }
            );
        }

        setLayout(layout);
        setWindowTitle("buttons");
        setModal(false);
    }

private:

    void handleButtonClick(QPushButton* clicked) {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText(clicked->text() + " clicked.");
        msgBox.exec();
    }

    std::vector<QPushButton*> buttons_;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. You can do it old-fashioned way, via `QObject::connect`
2. You assign buttons to `QButtonGroup` and have properly named slot for the group.

In latter case your slot would be receiving either `QAbstractButton*` argument or button's id as an `int`. There is no  need in fragile `sender()` call anymore.